# Keeping xml elements order in java object as a list of values after conversion of XML file to Java

Tags: java, xml

We have an XML file as mentioned below:-

```
<Transaction>
    <Buyr>
       <FrstNm>Vishwa</FrstNm>
    </Buyr>
    <Buyr>
       <FrstNm>PRIYA</FrstNm>
    </Buyr>
    <Buyr>
       <FrstNm>ABCD</FrstNm>
    </Buyr>
</Transaction>
```

Now what is happening after conversion from XML to Java, Java object is populated with  element values as List but not in the order they are defined in XML file.

Is there any way to keep the list of values in Java object same as they are defined in XML file?

Comment: Please show some code of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are unclear with your requirements.  How do you want to store this?  How do you want to deal with nested values?  Will the tag always be of the same name?  Here is a quick piece of code that will grab the value of your leaf node FrstNm

```
public List<String> populateArrayList(String xml, String tag) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
    DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
    is.getCharacterStream();

    Document doc = db.parse(is);
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    list.add(nodes.item(i).getTextContent());
    }

    return list;
}
```

Then obviously to call it

```
populateArrayList("yourXml", "FrstNm")
```

However I do not like this approach.  What is your end goal?  There are a lot of better xml technologies out there that might suite your case better.  Also that bit of code above only really works for leaf nodes.  You need to nest the for loop if you want it to be more thorough.  Please post your requirements and we can work off that.

Comment: Thanks @Christopher! The issue was coming from other part of the system. It has been identified. Thanks for the approach!